# How do I obtain the relative paths of two files in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I am writing a Bazel rule and I need to generate a file that contains references to other files. The references should be relative paths.

How do I obtain the relative path as a `string` between two `File` objects?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two files `one` and `two`, you could do some ugly magic similar to https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/5bfcb1a684550626ce138fe0fe8f5f702b3764c3/lib/paths.bzl#L156

I hope the following serves as a starting point:

```py
print(one.path, two.path, "/".join([".." for x in two.dirname.split("/")] + [one.basename]))
```